# Google Ads API getting Customer ID

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-ads-api

I want to create a ads video reporting tool. So I used Google Ads API. For that I need to get customer ID. There are some programming examples. But I want to use an HTTP request endpoint. I cannot find any method for getting customer ID's with HTTP request. Is there any method for getting customer_id with HTTP request?